# Read a named attribute from a WMA file on Win XP or later?

Tags: c#, windows-xp

How in C# may I read a named attribute e.g. Title from a WMA file on Win XP or later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method to read (and modify/write) WMA metadata attributes is to use [the Windows Media Format SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758036%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In particular the IWMHeaderInfo interface has the functions you want: [GetAttributeByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [GetAttributeCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetAttributeByIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You will have to write P/Invoke code in C# in order to use this COM-based API.

Another option which may be easier would be to use a library such as NAudio which has a WindowsMediaFormat assembly for reading and writing WMA files. With NAudio the task of reading attributes becomes pretty simple.

```
using (var wmaStream = new NAudio.WindowsMediaFormat.WmaStream(fileName))
{
    titleAttribute = wmaStream["Title"];
    authorAttribute = wmaStream["Author"];
    //  ...
    // read other meta tag attributes
}
```

You can find some more [details about reading and writing WMA meta tags using NAudio](http://mdinescu.com/software-development/21-how-to-read-and-write-wma-meta-tags-programatically-using-c) in a post I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution without any strange frameworks using. 
So I propose just to read the file bytewise using pure native .Net:

```
using System.IO;    
...
string metaStr = string.Empty;

            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(wmaUrl))
            {
                byte[] b = new byte[3000];

                fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length);

                metaStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b, 0, 3000);                
                metaStr = metaStr.Replace("\0", "");

                int metaStart = metaStr.IndexOf("<?xml version");
                metaStr = metaStr.Substring(metaStart);

                int metaEnd = metaStr.IndexOf("</recordingDetails>");
                metaStr = metaStr.Substring(0, metaEnd) + "</recordingDetails>";               
            }
```

Now metaStr contains the Comments field of WMA file description, which is usually called an Audio file MetaData.

Just remember, that this Comment field can be updated by other users and can contain other tags (not "recordingDetails" as shown above), so you should use your own custom substrings to define necessary MetaData borders.